# Different Date_Select Choices According to Different Select :Categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date

A user has two options: 'Monthly Average' or 'One-Time Instance.' Upon selecting one in the _form is there a way to use javascript or something to adjust the format of f.date_select in the _form according to the user's choice?

Upon selecting 'Monthly Average' I want the user to only see and select from: **month and year.** Upon selecting 'One-Time Instance' I want the user to see and select from: **day, month, and year.**

**_form.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_for(@quantified) do |f| %>
  <% if @quantified.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quantified.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this quantified from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @quantified.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="america">
<form>
   <%= f.select :categories, Quantified::CATEGORIES %>

   <br>
   <br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Name' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :result, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :metric, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric' %>
  </div>

    <div class="date-group">
      <label> Date: </label>
      <%= f.date_select :date, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
    </div>


<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to quantifieds_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @quantified, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>

</form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**quantified.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Monthly Average') }
  scope :instance, -> { where(categories: 'One-Time Instance') }

 CATEGORIES = ['Monthly Average', 'One-Time Instance']
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help!